# Rails: is there a better way to prepend view path rather then before_action hook?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have nested categorized folders for views, e.g: main class "Baby" has_many sub-classes "Boy", "Girl", "Alien" etc., that have their corresponding views in sub-folders of baby views: 
"app/views/babies/boys", "app/views/babies/girls"...

Rails don't recognize sub-folders for views by default, so I use before_action hook in controller, e.g.:

```
class BoysController < ApplicationController
before_action :subfolderview, except: [:create, :destroy, :update]
...
private
  def subfolderview
    prepend_view_path Rails.root + 'app' + 'views/babies'
  end
end
```

There is also a way I know of:

```
render :template => "babies/boys/..."
```

Can I somehow configure application.rb to do all the job? Like(both don't work):

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'views', 'babies', 'boys', '{*/}')]
```

or:

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'views', 'babies', '{*/}')]
```

I think there should be a way to do helper_method or some other kung-fu of which I am not acknowledged yet, but can't find it in google. Help me, please.

Comment: What's wrong with doing `render 'babies/boys/...`?

Comment: @Iceman, well, because it is the same? ...Or not? 
I can use 'render' again by 'before_action' callback with more code or writing it in each action, what is not DRY.

Comment: hmm, I never tried something like this, but can't you use routing for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Fallenhero mentioned above, routing is the way to do this.

`config/routes.rb`:

```
namespace :babies do # /babies/boys, /babies/girls, /babies/aliens
  resources :boys, :girls, :aliens
end
```

classes BoysController/GirlsController/etc should be enclosed in Babies Module:

```
module Babies
  class BoysController < ApplicationController
    # ...
  end
end
```

corresponding files moved into subfolder, like:

```
app/controllers/babies/boys_controller.rb
```

the corresponding layout folders goes also into subfolder:

```
app/views/babies/boys
```

ps: while doing so routes/pathes will change: `boys`/`edit_boy`/etc. will become `babies_boys`/`edit_babies_boy`/etc.